# Delphi OpenCL integration - sha256

Tags: delphi, opencl, sha256

is there any simple way to generate string list using `TStringList` or `TMemoryStrean` and send it dynamically to opencl code and calculate their sha256 hash with my graphic card?

I have 10M+ files generated (on a hourly basis) from my application and need to write their sha256 hash (one shot - bulk) to the same file name as original but with .hsh extension.

I am using Delphi 7 with `DCPcrypt2` unit that generating me hashes for now,  but it has **very** slow performance.

I have Intel graphic card compatible with OpenCL and want to make performance test and improve my app performance.

my part of code how I am doing it for now:

```
uses ..... ,DCPcrypt2,DCPsha256;

type
  ...
  sha256: TDCP_sha256;

var 
  result, ss:string;
  i, x: integer;
  myDigestSha2: array[0..31] of byte;
  f:textfile;

//collecting file names in a cycle that running few minutes to the TStringList

...

  for x := 1 to TStringList1.items.count do 
  begin
    ss := TStringList1.items[x];
    sha256.Burn;
    sha256.Init;
    sha256.UpdateStr(ss);
    sha256.Final(myDigestSha2);

    for i:= 0 to 31 do
      result := result + IntToHex(myDigestSha2[i],2);

    assignfile(f,'myfile.hsh');
    rewrite(f);
    writeln (f,result);
    closefile(f);
  end;
```

however this code works, it's very slow and eating a lot of my CPU.

Thanks for answers and sorry for my bad English;

Comment: Your code is broken. Lists use zero based indices. You overrun the buffer. Open the same file for every string is hugely expensive. Optimise and correct your code before you give up on it.

Comment: typical sha256 performance is more than 200MB/s so it shouldn't be a problem when reading from a HDD. If your platform is 64 bit, try sha512

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - customers requires sha256 encrypting,  I am using 64 bit OS (Win7)  Also HDD is not a problem too, the bottleneck is my CPU usage , when the procedure running, it eats one of my CPU (Delphi cannot use all 8 cores I have or yes? )

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - it was just an example what procedures I am using - not the exact code (I must hide 90% of code because the security of customers - I hope you understand it)  - I asked that question to reduce my CPU usage and utilize my GPU - if you can give me some hint, I will appreciate it..  I googled around a lot, believe me, but not found openCL code example for generating sha hashes

Comment: You can for sure use all 8 cores.

Comment: did you try this project https://github.com/Fruneng/opencl_sha_al_im/blob/master/sha256/sha256.cl as a dll calling?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik  never tried that, and to be honest I don't know how to do it.. I found only one mini app that made calculations based on .cl files. do you have some idea how to call .cl from Delphi?

Comment: @user2850599 https://code.google.com/archive/p/delphi-opencl/  and http://lab4.fme.vutbr.cz/heatlab/OpenCLforDelphi.html

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik  Thanks a lot! I found this source for D7 earlier, but with combo of .cl file you gave me a link I will make experiments and implement to my app...  No more freezing apps for my customers !  :)  Thanks !

Comment: @user2850599 you could write your own c++ wrapper but takes more time.

Comment: I assume either TStringList1 isn't actually a TStringList? TStringList doesn't have and Items[] property. If so, use a less confusing name. If it is, give us corrected code, as it is distracting.

Comment: Aslo, IIRC the implementation of IntToHex in older versions of Delphi was very slow - it was effectively a wrapper around Format('%x'). As you know it is a byte, there will be much faster ways to convert to hex.

Comment: If possible profile the code, manually if required, or check out https://www.delphitools.info/samplingprofiler/ for a free profiler.

Comment: @GerryColl  - tried with format ('%x')  , it slower by 2 seconds / 1M processed files than IntToHex  original time: 11 seconds, new time 13.1 seconds +/-

Comment: I wasn;t suggesting to use it, only to check if it isn't part of the bottleneck. Don't guess, profile! BTW by older versions, I'm not sure when it changed. May have been D6 -> D7, I remember it causing a slowdown in some code a long time ago

Comment: My bottleneck is definitely in hash calculation + first 2 minutes in every hour, customers are unable to access webserver because of high load of CPU (scheduled task recalculating new files with hashes)  That's the reason I want to utilize my GPU

Comment: Maybe you can disallow some cores for the software so it can be used by visitors?